# Maven imported dependencies don't get resolved if used in a profile

Tags: maven, import, dependency-management, resolve, profiles

We have taken all the dependencies to two separate pom files with dependencyManagement Sections. The requirement is to allow building a module with snapshot dependencies and release with release versions.These two pom files(**X** and **Y**) contain all the permitted snapshot versions of all modules and all the release versions of all modules. So a module pom file has a dependencyManagement section that imports pom file with release dependencies and a profile that is to be used for builds that contains a dependencyManagement section that imports the pom file with snapshot dependencies. But the problem is, the imported dependencies from the dependency management section in the profile does not get resolved at a build (eventhough the profile is active). If we remove the dependencyManagement section outside the profile (the one with the release versions), these get resolved. Is this expected behaviour? If so, why? Or is this a bug in maven? Tested in both maven 2 and 3.

The following sample pom files show the problem.

project X

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>X</artifactId>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>X</name>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>test</groupId>
       <artifactId>a</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>test</groupId>
       <artifactId>b</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Project Y

```
<project>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>Y</name>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>test</groupId>
       <artifactId>a</artifactId>
       <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>test</groupId>
       <artifactId>b</artifactId>
       <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>test</groupId>
       <artifactId>c</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Project Z

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Z</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Z</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>X</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>non-release</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build>true</build>
        </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
      </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

**mvn help:active-profiles** returns non-release.
But mvn help:effective-pom returns **test:a:1.0, test:b:1.0, test:c:1.0-SNAPSHOT**

I want to get snapshot versions for **a** and **b** also.

Any idea why it happens like this?
If this is because of the order it gets resolved, how can I get over with it get snapshot dependencies resolved at builds without mentioning a profile and get release versions resolved at release time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a `dependencyManagement` section in the main section of POM, outside profile definitions. This means that definitions included there are profile-independent and so are always taken into account. There is no option in Maven to make it "forget" a dependency, once defined — except by using profiles.

Consider moving the `maven:X:1.0:pom` to a profile then.

Comment: Hi @MaDa you are right. I was wondering whether the import in the profile was not getting resolved. But what actually happens seem to be the resolved dependencies are already set by the **dependencyManagement** section in the main section of POM and therefore the imported by the profile values are not taken into account.
Planning to move it into a profile.

Comment: What should I do if the section has to be defined in and outside the profile, with a difference in version number? Does it need to be repeated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "the section". I think it deserves a separate question.